# Registering a custom VirtualUriMapper in Magnolia CMS

Tags: java, magnolia

I try to implement a custom VirtualUriMapping (RegexpVirtualUriMapping but with localization) for Magnolia CMS version 6.1.3.
Unfortunately, I can not use my class in light-modules (yaml definition). My class (**I18nVirtualUriMapping.java**) is placed in a module, which is a dependency of my custom webapp (magnolia-community-webapp archetype). How do I have to register my VirtualUriMapper?

This is the custom class **I18nVirtualUriMapping.java** (shortened):

```
package my.magnolia.module.mapping;

import info.magnolia.virtualuri.mapping.DefaultVirtualUriMapping;

public class I18nVirtualUriMapping extends DefaultVirtualUriMapping {
    
}
```

Definition of a virtual-uri mapping in the light-module **news-ROOT.yaml**:

```
class: my.magnolia.module.mapping.I18nVirtualUriMapping
fromUri: /news(.*).html
toUri: forward:/News-Detail.html?news=$1
```

Defining the mapping in a light-module, I get this **error**:

```
2021-05-27 02:10:20,556 WARN  agnolia.transformer.ClassPropertyBasedTypeResolver: Encountered the 'class' property but failed to resolved the type from its value: [my.magnolia.module.mapping.I18nVirtualUriMapping]
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: my.magnolia.module.mapping.I18nVirtualUriMapping
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_131]
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_131]
...
```

Answer (score 2):

After long hours of searching, I found the solution myself. It's about dependency injection (https://docs.magnolia-cms.com/product-docs/Modules/Dependency-injection-and-inversion-of-control.html).

```
public class I18nVirtualUriMapping extends DefaultVirtualUriMapping {
    private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(I18nVirtualUriMapping.class);

    private final I18nVirtualMappingModule module;

    @Inject
    public I18nVirtualUriMapping(final I18nVirtualMappingModule module) {
        this.module = module;
    }

    //... 
}
```